# Dart: Referring to Singleton class from within itself

Tags: class, dart, singleton

I have a singleton class and I would like to refer to it from within itself, however I am getting a `CyclicInitializationError (Reading static variable 'instance' during its initialization)` when trying to do so.

Here is an example:

```
void main(){
  Singleton newSingleton = Singleton();
  print(newSingleton.member);
}

class Singleton {
  static final instance = Singleton._internal();
  Singleton._internal();
  factory Singleton(){
    return instance;
  }
  String member = "hello";
  String hamburger = instance.member; // This line causes the error to be thrown
}
```

Comment: This might be an X-Y problem.  Why do you want to do this?  If you want two indepndent members to be initialized to the same value, you could initialize both of them from a `static` member.  If you want one member to be an alias to another, you could provide `get` and/or `set` methods instead.

Comment: I'm writing a Flutter application and I want to separate control logic from view logic in my pages, so I have class `HomePage` that uses a `HomePageController`. Currently I have a drawer in `HomePageController` that references a method to handle selecting a drawer element. However, I can't refer to the method from within the class because `only static members can be accessed in initializers`. I thought that by using a singleton class I could then refer to to the members, but so far I have no luck.

Comment: Your suggestion to use `get` and `set` worked though. I can access class members in the class, singleton or not.